What is the correct syntax to use for IF conditions in ReportingCloud templates?
It is possible to add conditional statement to a MS template to use with Reporting Cloud textcontrol ? How to do it?
This is not working.
{ IF { MERGEFIELD Heading } = "Notes" "" { MERGEFIELD Heading } }
Show the merge field "heading" only if is different than "Notes".

I'm not familiar with Reporting Cloud, but see that you can enter an IF field using a dialog box. But is it possible to enter the normal Word special field braces in there, or some other way? Otherwise, I just wonder whether Reporting Cloud only allows plain text in the IF result.

In addition, the documentation for the Reporting Cloud API suggests that the kind of field nesting available in Word is not at present available in ReportingCloud:https://docs.textcontrol.com/textcontrol/wpf/ref.txtextcontrol.documentserver.fields.iffield.class.htm . Perhaps better to open a support issue on the product's website.

It is not possible they said. The concept is "pre-shaped" data , so provide the proper data already in the json data
